# Error TypeError: data[j][0].setMilliseconds is not a function assignEditUrls @ Code.gs:17

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am new to Google Scripts. So, I am trying to learn. I have used the script below from a Youtube video that shows how to write a script to create an URL when a Google form is submitted. This should allow the user to go back and re-edit the form. There is a sample script to use in the youtube information. However, when I run this script, I get the following error message.

> Error TypeError: data[j][0].setMilliseconds is not a function
> assignEditUrls  @ Code.gs:17

I saw in another post response that "j" is not a good variable. I tried changing that but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the script as written.

```
function assignEditUrls() {
var form = FormApp.openById('1Jh35nIdGtT0gCTWNSW4vAnC9L-cZY-pdOnHy2MFuL2g');

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Event_Information');

var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var urlCol = 52; 
var responses = form.getResponses();
var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
}
for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
}
sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setMilliseconds()` is a method of `Date`. Your code is returning the referred method because the value returned by `data[j][0]` is not a `Date` object.

In order to help you debug your code you might include `console.log(JSON.stringify(data[j][0]))` before line 17.